# How to open popup window from each of dynamically generate tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to open a popup window from a parent window. I have two `tr` and each `tr` has a apply button and as soon as I click on the apply button it will open a popup window.

But somehow, popup window gets opened for first tr only apply button meaning as soon as I click on the Apply Button for the first tr, popup window gets opened.

But for the second tr apply button, popup window doesn't gets opened.

I am not sure why it is not working.

Below is my full code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

* { font-family: Trebuchet MS; }
#containerdiv {width:90%; height: 90%; display: none; position: fixed;margin-top: 5%; margin-left: 5%; background:#FFF; border: 1px solid #666;border: 1px solid #555;box-shadow: 2px 2px 40px #222; z-index: 999999;}
/*#containerdiv iframe {display:none; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; border: none; }*/
#blockdiv {background: #000; opacity:0.6;  position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top:0; left:0; display:none;}
ul { padding:10px; background: #EEE; position: absolute; height: 200px; overflow: scroll;}
ul li {color: #222; padding: 10px; font-size: 22px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;  }
h3 { font-size: 26px; padding:18px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; }
#close { top: 13px;position: absolute;right: 13px; padding: 10px; background: #EEE; border: 1px solid #CCC;}
#close:hover {  cursor: pointer; background: #E5E5E5 }

#apply { top: 13px;position: absolute;left: 13px; padding: 10px; background: #EEE; border: 1px solid #CCC;}
#apply:hover {  cursor: pointer; background: #E5E5E5 }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

function open(url) {
    $('#blockdiv').fadeIn();
    $('#iframe').attr('src', url);
    $('#containerdiv').fadeIn();   
}

function close() {  
    $('#blockdiv').fadeOut();
    $('#containerdiv').fadeOut();  
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul').css({width: $('#containerdiv').width(),height:    $('#containerdiv').height()})
     $('#close').click( function() { close() })
     $('#JN_apply').click( function() { open($(this).data('url')); })

});

</script>
</head>


<body bgcolor="#F8F8F8">

<table width="850" border="0" align="left" style="table-layout:fixed; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;" >
<tr bgcolor = "#C4D3D9" align = "center" height = "10" style="font-size:13px"> 
<th width = "65%">Description</th> 
<th width = "10%">Apply</th>
</tr><tr align="left" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
  <td style="word-wrap: break-word; border-top:none" valign="top">
    <p><span style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold">
    <a href="some_url"> Field Specialist Program </a>
    </span>
    <br />
  </td>
<td>
<input id= "JN_apply" type=button value="Apply" data-url="http://www.yahoo.com/">
</td>
</tr>
<tr align="left" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
  <td style="word-wrap: break-word; border-top:none" valign="top">
    <p><span style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold">
    <a href="some_url"> Field Specialist Material </a>
    </span>
    <br />
  </td>
<td>
<input id= "JN_apply" type=button value="Apply" data-url="http://www.google.com/">
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="blockdiv"></div>
<div id="containerdiv">
    <iframe id="iframe" style="width:100%; height: 100%; outline: 1px solid red;"></iframe>
    <span id="close">Close</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3wgm/) that I have created. In that you will see that if you click on first Apply button then the popup will get open, but as soon as you click on the second apply button, the popup won't get open. Can anybody explain me why this is happening? And how to resolve this?

Comment: functions open() and close() already exists - choose different names

Comment: meaning? I didn't understand..

Answer (score 2):

Your html is invalid: the `id` attribute is supposed to be unique. When you use the selector `#JN_apply"` it selects just one of the buttons (in most browsers this will be the first, as you have seen).

You should change each one to use a `class` instead of an `id`:

```
<input class="JN_apply" type=button value="Apply" data-url="http://www.yahoo.com/">
```

...and then change the jQuery selector to match:

```
$('.JN_apply').click( function() { open($(this).data('url')); })
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p3wgm/3/

Note also that it's not a good idea to create global functions called `open()` and `close()` because there are already built-in functions [`open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open) and [`close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.close) and your functions will overwrite these. Perhaps `openPopup()` and `closePopup()` or similar? Or define them inside your document ready handler so that they're not global, which would probably be better regardless of the names. Or if they're only ever called from one place (like in your example) just put that code directly in the click handlers.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I have one more doubt. The same code doesn't works in IE but it works fine in Chrome. Do you know what can be the reason? And how to fix it?

Comment: What happens in IE? Any errors in the console? The updated fiddle seemed to work in IE (10) the same as Chrome, though neither was willing to actually display Yahoo or Google in the popup because of the cross-site security settings.